# Lazy init for activemq datasource

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, applicationcontext

I was wondering if there is any way for lazy init of activemq persistence. The problem is that I don't want to specify user and password of the database beforehand, but rather let user enter these values after application's initialization. So, for example user starts application and then is required to enter database username and password. After he does so, the application initializes activemq persistence using database connection provided by user.

```
    <amq:persistenceFactory>
        <amq:journalPersistenceAdapterFactory journalLogFiles="4" dataDirectory="./journal-data" dataSource="#postgre-ds">
            <amq:statements>
                <amq:statements binaryDataType="VARCHAR(250)"/>
            </amq:statements>
        </amq:journalPersistenceAdapterFactory>
    </amq:persistenceFactory>
```

wherere postgre-ds

```
<bean id="postgre-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:someURL"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="pa55w0rd"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="200"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

so I want first get values for username and password and after that initialize persistence. Thanks )

Comment: Perhaps don't use Spring!

Comment: Why do you need to enter the credentials manually ? It seems weird...

Comment: well, you don't know database name, username and password in advance. Once the app is deployed, user will enter these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea with spring is to wire up these things at startup, which covers 99% of the usecases.

There is nothing magical about it. It's just plain java objects anyway. If you need more control over the life cycle and input parameters, then go ahead and do the things manually.

```
DataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setUsername( getInput() );
// ... set all parameters needed
JournalPersistenceAdapterFactory factory = new JournalPersistenceAdapterFactory();
factory.setDataDirectoryFile(data);
//.. set all parameters needed
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.setPersistenceFactory(factory);
broker.addConnector(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.DEFAULT_BROKER_BIND_URL);
// More config goes here
broker.start();
```